# Cutting a polygon from TIFF with Python

Tags: python, gdal

I would like to cut out a roof of building from a TIFF. I have the TIFF and the layer and I will show below. I have found a code but it contains not enough co-ordinates.

My TIFF with layer:
I would like to cut out a roof.

[image]

My code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
bbox = (xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax)
gdal.Translate('output_crop_raster.tif', 'input_raster.tif', projWin = bbox)
```

My raster data and buildings layer:

[image]

Comment: You mean the roof of one of the buildings, or the bounding box of all?

Comment: The roof of one of the building by python.

Comment: A specific single one of them or one raster file for each roof?

Comment: How does the tutorial not help you? https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/masking-by-shapefile.html#masking-a-raster-using-a-shapefile

Comment: I'am getting error.

Comment: ValueError: Input shapes do not overlap raster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `rasterio` and `geopandas`. First read your roofs using [`geopandas.read_file()`](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/geopandas.read_file.html#geopandas-read-file) and then clip your raster using [`rasterio.mask.mask()`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.mask.html#rasterio.mask.mask). A tutorial can be found here: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/masking-by-shapefile.html#masking-a-raster-using-a-shapefile

```py
import rasterio
import rasterio.mask
import geopandas as gpd


# Read roofs
gdf = gpd.read_file("input_shapes.geojson")  # Your roofs
gdf.set_index("roof_id")
roof = gdf.loc[1234]  # Your roof id


# Open input raster and write masked (clipped) output raster
with rasterio.open("input_raster.tif") as src:
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, [roof["geometry"]], crop=True)
    out_meta = src.meta

    out_meta.update(
        {
            "height": out_image.shape[1],
            "width": out_image.shape[2],
            "transform": out_transform,
        }
    )

    with rasterio.open("output_raster.tif", "w", **out_meta) as dest:
        dest.write(out_image)
```

PS.: I'm using `geopandas` instead of `fiona` because it will make it easier for you to select the roof that you want to use for clipping.
PPS.: I have not tested the above code myself

Comment: AttributeError: module 'rasterio' has no attribute 'mask'

Comment: According to the linked tutorial, you must also `import rasterio.mask`. I've added it to my answer

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wycinanie.py", line 15, in <module>
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask(src, [roof['geometry']], crop=True)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: I think you must import `rasterio.mask`, but still use its module function: `import rasterio.mask; [...]; rasterio.mask.mask(...);`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wycinanie.py", line 15, in <module>
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, [roof['geometry']], crop=True)
  File "/home/gis/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasterio/mask.py", line 182, in mask
    shape_mask, transform, window = raster_geometry_mask(
  File "/home/gis/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasterio/mask.py", line 90, in raster_geometry_mask
    raise ValueError('Input shapes do not overlap raster.')
ValueError: Input shapes do not overlap raster.

Comment: Sounds like you must specify CRS correctly. Hard to say without sample data. Could you upload sample data?

Comment: I have just edited my post and I added some data.

Answer (score 2):

gdal.Translate will give you the MBR of the building from the raster. You should use gdal.Warp with `cutline` option to get only the raster over the building footprint.

```
gdal.Warp('output_crop_raster.tif', 'input_raster.tif', cutlineDSName='your_vector_layer', cropToCutline=True)
```

If no SRS defined in your vector layer you should also add `srcSRS=EPSG:nnnn`.
You can have more buildings in your vector layer.

For example before cutting in QGIS:

[image]

and after cutting:

[image]

Comment: Could you show any example? I would like to see some code.

Comment: The code is there. `gdal.Warp`, nothing else to do.

Comment: Yeah, but gdal.Warp will cut out every roof but I would like to choose the roof which I want to cut out.

Comment: You should extract building features in a loop from your vector layer using attribute or spatial filter, see: https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html